# how do i submit a pastebin or pastee from an android app and get the url back

Tags: java, api, android-studio, pastebin

ok so heres what i want to achieve:
i want to submit to pastebin or pastee a string(big string) with a custom title and recieve back the url to it as a string (this needs to be done as a guest)

before i continue, i have searched and there is lots of different api's some java i have tried them all and none have worked for me, theres a fair few posts but none with a definative answer.

ok so lets go with what i know (or think i know)

i need atleast : (according to http://pastebin.com/api)
api_dev_key (i have my api key)
api_option=paste 
api_paste_code (the code we want to paste)

the title is optional but is :
api_paste_name=

the url for submission is :
*pastebin web page /api/api_post.php

so in theory 
*pastebin web page /api/api_post.php/api_dev_key=myprivateapikey&api_option=paste&api_paste_name=testpaste&api_paste_code=hello%20world

should create a pastebin titled testpaste with the content hello world

instead it creates "This paste has been removed!"

so thats the first hurdle (yes i have double checked my api key)

then comes im not really sure how to get the address back after the key is submitted.

all in all im totaly confused (it doesnt help that i have been reading about a thousand and one api java's and guides and none seem to work.

the code i had cobbled together at one point is :

http://pastebin.com/4PVFH8tR

the alternative is pastee but its api is very very undocumented

*it counted them as links so had to make them non url so i could ask the question